# Looking for a well-regarding JSON library benchmark, preferably cross-platform and language neutral

Tags: library, c++, cross-platform, json, benchmarking

I'm trying to find a well-regarded JSON library benchmark, preferably cross-platform, preferably language independent. I'm most concerned about C++ performance on Linux, but would like to make comparisons and find something that works well on macOS and Windows too. Also, I'd like to benchmark implementations in C/C++ as well as other languages.

I've found a few benchmarks that are interesting, but they all seem to be Java only and the results aren't that impressive.

Is there a benchmark that can be considered definitive for comparing solutions?

BTW, this is not a duplicate. I'm looking for a CSV benchmark too...figured I should ask the question separately.

Comment: What do you mean by a “library benchmark”?

Comment: For parsing and for other common operations with a well-defined data set, I’d like to see #records per CPU clock cycle. For different data types and arrays, insertions, deletions.

Comment: Add that detail as an edit to your Question.